# Infinite summation of a function when residue theorem doesn't apply?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I need to calculate the infinite summation below
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(z_n-4)^2(z_n+2)^2}\ln\left[1+\frac{(z_n-4)(z_n+2)}{(z_n-5)(z_n+3)}\right],$$ where $z_n=\mathrm{i}\frac{2n\pi}{\beta}$ and $\beta$ is a fixed positive number.

There're singularities at $z=5,z=-3$ or the roots $z=1\pm\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$ of the argument inside $\ln$. The branch cut of $\ln$ prevents us from using residue theorem together with functions like $\frac{1}{\mathrm{exp}{[\beta z]}-1}$ to evaluate the summation. So this way is wrong at least for this case? I think the summation is not divergent. There must be a way to evaluate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, clearly the function isn't defined at $\;z=3,5\;$ and where expression inside parentheses equals zero... *at least*

Comment: As regards this "infinite summation", What is exactly your original problem? Maybe the residue at infinity is involved...

Comment: it should reduce to $\sum_{n= 0}^\infty \frac{\ln(n + a)}{(n+b)^2}$